# Laravel erro na instalação

Tags: php, laravel

Gente, estou usando o mac e tentando instalar o Laravel. Já instalei o `composer`, rodei a linha de comando documentada no framework :

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Ele executa tudo ok, porém quando tento

```
laravel new blog
```

Ele dá que o comando laravel não existe.

Estou criando dentro do htdocs do xammp.

Como poderia arrumar isso ?

Obrigado

Comment: O comando não seria, `php laravel new blog`?

Comment: amigo da comando desconhecido

Comment: Esta usando windows ou linux?

Comment: MAC mas acredito que seja semelhante ao linux

Comment: Não pode ser via **Composer** ?

Comment: Entao estou seguindo um livro, e ele usa o comando direto no laravel ... Não sabe como posso Arrumar >

Comment: Então, mas o Laravel é instalado via Composer. Você instalou o Composer ?

Comment: sim, instalei o composer tudo certo, agora até o laravel usando este site : https://blog.butecopensource.org/tutorial-laravel-5/ , porem qnd acesso localhost/teste1/public da erro 500

Comment: usei o buscador dentro do xampp com .bash_profile e me retornou dois arquivos mas nenhum com esse nome

Comment: Meu, apaga esse Xamposta. E instala o **Mamp**. https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Comment: ok estou instalando

Comment: funcionou amigoooooo finalmente.... S'o uma pergunta, como posso criar um atalho no terminal ? exemplo toda vez irer usar o cd /xxx/xxx/xxxx gostaria de transformar esse comando em um goDevWeb

Comment: Não manjo disso, cara. Mas que bom que funcionou. Faça uma pergunta de novo. Tenho certeza que alguém deve saber aqui.

Comment: ok  obrigado pela ajuda e paciencia XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ter o `/Users/seu-nome-de-usuario/.composer/vendor/bin` no seu Path para que o executável do laravel  possa ser utilizado em qualquer pasta do sistema.

Para verificar se seu path contem o caminho do composer execute o comando

```
echo $PATH
```

e veja o output

Caso não esteja você pode adicionar o caminho com o comando

```
sudo vim /etc/paths
```

E adicionar na ultima linha

```
/Users/seu-nome-de-usuario/.composer/vendor/bin
```

**ou** caso você sobrescreva os paths nas configurações do seu terminal você pode utilizar

```
sudo vim ~/.zshrc
```

e adicionar a linha

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/seu-nome-de-usuario/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Comment: amigo editei o arquivo e coloquei na ultima linha, mas sem resultados qnd uso $PATH ele não me mostra o caminho, o resultado é : /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Uma dica Alan, se você não usar o `@AugustoFurlan` no comentário ele não vai receber a sua mensagem, talvez ele não tenha lido teu comentário.

Comment: @augustoFurlan veja se você consegue editar o arquivo `~/.bashrc` e adicionar `export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/seu-nome-de-usuario/.composer/vendor/bin"` no final do arquivo.

> Lembre-se de trocar *seu-nome-de-usuario* pelo seu nome de usuário

Answer (score 1):

No xamp consegui resolver esse problema assim:

Abra o seu  `.bash_profile`:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

E copie a seguinte linha no final do arquivo:

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

Salve, e depois reinicie assim:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Qualquer coisa tente criar os seus projetos assim:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

É a mesma coisa de `laravel new project`.

Comment: amigo fui editar .bash e deu errado, não encontra o arquivo

Comment: pesquisa em todas suas pastas pela pasta xampp, depois pegue o endereço completo até o bin e troque pelo endereço correto.